# Is this phrase correct? "I see this program as a cornerstone in my process to become an excellent software engineer"

Tags: grammar, phrases

English is not my native language and somehow this phrase doesn't feel right. What do you guys think?

> I see this program as a cornerstone in my process to become an excellent software engineer.

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about what doesn't feel right to you. Are you concerned about the wording, the grammar, or something else?

Comment: I think it scares me.  Before you know it you'll be spouting terms like "code smell", "anti-pattern", "design patterns", "agile programming", "scrum", etc.  Which by itself would not be bad, if anyone understood what the terms meant.

Comment: "Cornerstone in my process" is a pretty bad mixed metaphor. Also, no need to call it "my process" or even to use "process" at all. If you like stones: *An important milestone on my way to being an excellent software engineer.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not wrong, but it sounds a little odd. I think it's  "my process" - "my path" or "my route" may be better. Then there's the business of mixing metaphors: a cornerstone belongs in a building, not in a path or process. So maybe cornerstone needs to change too:  "... an important step on my route to ..."?

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks a lot for your insight I think I will change it to:
I see this program as an important step in my path to become an excellent software engineer.

Comment: You're most welcome!

Comment: I have to disagree...  The only word that stood out to me as awkward was "excellent".  Technically, it is not wrong, but it is a word used by younger people to describe anything they appreciate. Scrap "to become an excellent..." for "to becoming a proficient..."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sugestion, I think it does improve my sentence and therefor will make the change. Again, thanks for your suggestion.